# Javascript fade in with jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, fadein

How can i make Javascript fadein like this:
http://www.bewerberfilm.com

The Videos fadein from left and from the right. The Textboxes above the videos are fade in with different second settings. How can i realize that?
can anyone show me or help me? I have no experience in JS/Jquery but i want to learn that language.

Comment: You can checkout this: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/. There's a "fadeInLeft" which should be what you are looking for

Comment: You can always made by yourself. That effect only makes a transition between on two propertys: Opacity and Position. With [jquery animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) you can make that effect playing with a transition Opacity 0 -> 1 and Left/Margin-Left/Padding-Left (or right) from X to Y

Comment: Thank your for your replies! @Alekos: How can i animate it that the box just fade in when i scroll to the box?
frikinside: Thank your for your info!

Answer (score 2):

You can add a listener to the `scroll` event like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var element = $('#MyElement');

  var running = false;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log(element.position());
    if (element.position().top <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight() && !running) {
      console.log("Triggering animation");
      running = true;
      element.removeClass().addClass('fadeInLeftBig animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
        $(this).removeClass();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#MyElement {
  height: 40px;
  clear: both;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>adsada
  <br/>
</p>
<div id="MyElement"></div>
```

Here a working fiddle, the entire css was too big for the StackOverflow snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/df19qumg/